# How to count the occurrence of distinct values in a column where respective values in the other column is same?

Tags: sql

It has been a few days since I am studying SQL, and right now I am trying to solve this scenario.
Let us assume we have this table.

Click to see the table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGjfo.png)

And what I want is to get the number of distinct loc's each user has. More specifically, user ana has 2 distinct locs (2,4), ben has only 1(3).

Click to see the table[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFivX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Standard grouping in SQL:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT loc) FROM t1 GROUP BY user
```